# error UNHANDLED REJECTION TypeError: Cannot read property 'internal' of undefined

Tags: node.js, gatsby

I have a Gatsby project that runs with the `gatsby develop` command.

When I rename it, it no longer runs.

Instead it throws an UNHANDED REJECTION error. `TypeError: Cannot read property 'internal' of undefined`.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I deleted the .cache folder and executed the `gatsby develop` command.

It appears that there are files inside the .cache that have absolute references to the root folder.